# Why some of the task were not "greened" in Azure Devops CI pipelines after it successfully build?

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I'm deploying my Angular app in azure. I'm wondering that there might be a problem around here that's why my release failed.
Is it normally like that? Even the initialize job from the beginning it is always grey.

[image: build steps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So they do not have anything to do with your app failing on the release side.

They are the included system tasks that will always run in any pipeline. While they could technically fail, the probably won't. Could think of them as always having a neutral status, that doesn't matter much to you, as apposed to a step that you create, that could pass or fail.